# Chrome Extension : Manifest version 3 issue : Uncaught TypeError: global.XMLHttpRequest is not a constructor

Tags: chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I have developed chrome extension in manifest version 2 and I am trying to convert it to manifest version 3.

I have changed the manifest file as per the version 3 rules but i am getting below error(image attached) while installing extension in the chrome://extension.

[image: Uncaught TypeError: global.XMLHttpRequest is not a constructor]

I haven't used this code `var xhr = new global.XMLHttpRequest()` anywhere else in the code but don't know from where it is taking.
Can anyone please help me to solve this issue.

I had created the extension in AngularJs and I am creating build folder using script. I am using gulp and browserify to make a bundle. I think this is coming from any library but not sure from which library it is coming.

Here are my devDependencies in package.json file.

```
"devDependencies": {
"archiver": "^0.11.0",
"brfs": "^1.4.1",
"browserify": "^11.2.0",
"envify": "^3.0.0",
"eslint": "^1.5.1",
"fs-jetpack": "^0.7.0",
"gulp": "^3.8.11",
"gulp-base64": "^0.1.2",
"gulp-file-include": "^0.13.7",
"gulp-rename": "^1.2.0",
"gulp-sass": "^2.1.0",
"gulp-util": "^3.0.7",
"gulp-wrap": "^0.11.0",
"html2js-browserify": "0.0.2",
"http-server": "^0.8.5",
"vinyl-source-stream": "^1.1.0",
"watchify": "^3.6.1",
"yargs": "^1.3.1",
"opener": "^1.4.1",
"pre-commit": "^1.1.1",
"pretty-hrtime": "^1.0.1"},
```

Here is my code which i have used to make a bundle.

```
var bundleTask = function () {
return browserify({
    entries: './myProj/background/main.js'
})
.transform(envify)
.bundle()
.pipe(source('background.js'))
.pipe(gulp.dest('build/background'));};
```

Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Use multi-file search to find it.

Comment: Thanks @wOxxOm for the reply, Actually this is coming from any library i guess, because i searched in multi-file as well. I have updated the question, can you please check.

Comment: Search in your node_modules folder as well.

Comment: @wOxxOm, I guess this coming from the 'jsdom' library. I have used this library to access the window. If I don't use this library then it showing an error 'window is not defined'.

Comment: There's no DOM or window in the service worker. Why do you need it?